# Integration of JMX in Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have been meaning to monitor my wildfly in zabbix through JMX. The versions are listed below

1. wildfly: 20.0.0.1 final
2. zabbix: 5.0.7
3. java(that is present in wildfly host): openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14

**The issue i am facing while i run wildlfy is as follows.**

`-Xbootclasspath is no longer a supported option. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit`

My **standalone.conf** file looks like as below:

```
if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.bytemani,org.joss.logmanager"
fi

# Uncomment the following line to prevent manipulation of JVM options
# by shell scripts.
#
#PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS=true

#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath:/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.15.Final.jar"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

As per my research, i have found that my java version is not compatible and i dont know the work around process.

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the log manager on the boot class path?

Comment: yes @JamesR.Perkins, because if i dont i get an error regarding logmannger thats why

Comment: You should be able to use `Xbootclasspath/p`. Which agent are you using? I don't see it listed there.